# How to answer questions automatically using shell script

Tags: unix

How do i answer questions (appeared in terminal during installation of any X package or copying one file content into another when it asks to replace file) automatically from shell script. Please suggest any possible method.

Comment: shell questions are better served by either superUser or serverFault

Comment: I want to answer them automatically by running my script (assuming i am a root user).

Comment: i understand. im saying that stack overflow is intended for programming related questions. there are 2 sites in the stack exchange network better suited for shell questions - http://serverfault.com and http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a expect script, which could be used to automate your iteraction with the shell.

Reference this: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect, or just the man page.